# Use an empty instance of an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following simple interface `EmployerContact`.
How can I create an empty object, `mockEmployerContact` of type `EmployerContact` then assign values to the properties later? Does  it have to start with default values?
My `mockEmployerContact` object is undefined at the time I'm trying to set lastName and contactEmail.

```
export interface IEmployerContact {
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
}
```

...

```
mockEmployerContact: EmployerContact;

getEmployerContact() {
  this.employerService.GetEmployerProposalDetailsFromId(this.employerId, true).subscribe(data => {
    this.mockEmployerContact.lastName = data.lastName;
    this.mockEmployerContact.email = data.contactEmail;
  });
}
```

Comment: Why not create it? `this.mockEmployerContact = { lastName, contactEmail: email } = data;`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make that `mockEmployerContact: EmployerContact | undefined` and deal with the fact that the object isn't loaded until `getEmployerContact` was called and the request has finished.

Comment: I still see the error "lastName is undefined"  when attempting to assign `this.mockEmployerContact.lastName = data.lastName;`

Comment: The only thing i can find to work is `mockEmployerContact: EmployerContact = { lastName: undefined, email: undefined }; `

Comment: You could use `Partial<IEmployerContact>` for mocking where you need to, keeping `IEmployerContact` with properties that must be defined.

Answer (score 1):

In your interface, you set lastName and email to required properties on your object, so if you want to be able to fill those in later, you would need to set them as optional properties like so

```
interface IEmployerContact { lastName?: string; email?: string }
```

. TypeScript doesn't support init (ie Default) properties on interfaces.

Comment: I still see the error "lastName is undefined" whether these properties are nullable or not

Comment: The only thing i can find to work is mockEmployerContact: EmployerContact = { lastName: undefined, email: undefined };

Comment: @noclist that's because the properties themselves are not defined

Comment: Correct, with an interface you cannot set default/init values onto an objects properties, so the only thing that an interface will do is ensure that if you do set a property to required, that upon creating an object of type x, x.requiredProperty is defined